# Django: add user on admin page using custom user model

Tags: python, django, authentication

I defined a custom user model in my Django project, which defines the 'email' as the unique identifier. I created a custom user creation form following the Django documentation and registered it in my admin.py. When I start the web server, no errors are shown in the console.

My problem is, that the `add_form` on the admin page does not show the 'email' field, but only 'username', 'password1' and 'password2'

I read several how to's and tutorials and checked the Django documentation to resolve this issue and am afraid I am missing something.

## settings.py

```
# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'users.apps.UsersConfig'
]

AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'users.NewUser'
```

## model.py

```
# Custom User Account Model

from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin, BaseUserManager


class CustomAccountManager(BaseUserManager):
    """
    Custom user model manager where email is the unique identifiers for authentication instead of usernames.
    """
    def create_user(self, email, username, first_name, last_name, password=None, **other_fields):
        if not last_name:
            raise ValueError(_('Users must have a last name'))
        elif not first_name:
            raise ValueError(_('Users must have a first name'))
        elif not username:
            raise ValueError(_('Users must have a username'))
        elif not email:
            raise ValueError(_('Users must provide an email address'))

        user = self.model(
            email=self.normalize_email(email),
            username=username,
            first_name=first_name,
            last_name=last_name,
            **other_fields
        )
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)

        return user

    def create_superuser(self, email, username, first_name, last_name, password=None, **other_fields):
        """
        Create and save a SuperUser with the given email and password.
        """

        other_fields.setdefault('is_staff', True)
        other_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', True)
        other_fields.setdefault('is_admin', True)

        user = self.create_user(
            email=self.normalize_email(email),
            username=username,
            first_name=first_name,
            last_name=last_name,
            password=password,
            **other_fields
        )

        if other_fields.get('is_staff') is not True:
            raise ValueError('Superuser must be assigned to is_staff=True.')
        if other_fields.get('is_superuser') is not True:
            raise ValueError('Superuser must be assigned to is_superuser=True.')

        user.save(using=self._db)

        return user


class NewUser(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    # basic information
    email = models.EmailField(_('email address'), unique=True)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=150, unique=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=True)

    # Registration Date
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)  ## todo: unterschied zu 'auto_now_add=True'

    # Permissions
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_superuser = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    objects = CustomAccountManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['username', 'first_name', 'last_name']  # Note: USERNAME_FIELD not to be included in this list!

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email

    # For checking permissions. to keep it simple all admin have ALL permissons
    def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
        return self.is_admin

    # Does this user have permission to view this app? (ALWAYS YES FOR SIMPLICITY)
    def has_module_perms(self, app_label):
        return True

    @property
    def is_staff(self):
        "Is the user a member of staff?"
        # Simplest possible answer: All admins are staff
        return self.is_admin
```

## forms.py

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib import admin
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError

# Import custom user model
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
custom_user_model = get_user_model()


class CustomUserCreationForm(forms.ModelForm):
    """A form for creating new users. Includes all the required
    fields, plus a repeated password."""

    username = forms.CharField(label='Username', min_length=4, max_length=150)
    email = forms.EmailField(label='E-Mail')
    first_name = forms.CharField(label='First Name')
    last_name = forms.CharField(label='Last Name')

    password1 = forms.CharField(label='Password', widget=forms.PasswordInput)
    password2 = forms.CharField(label='Password confirmation', widget=forms.PasswordInput)

    class Meta:
        model = custom_user_model
        fields = ('username', 'first_name', 'last_name')

    def clean_password2(self):
        # Check that the two password entries match
        password1 = self.cleaned_data.get("password1")
        password2 = self.cleaned_data.get("password2")
        if password1 and password2 and password1 != password2:
            raise ValidationError("Passwords don't match")
        return password2

    def save(self, commit=True):
        # Save the provided password in hashed format
        user = super().save(commit=False)
        user.set_password(self.cleaned_data["password1"])
        if commit:
            user.save()

        return user
```

## admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin  # Helper Class for creating user admin pages

from .forms import CustomUserCreationForm  #, CustomUserChangeForm
from .models import NewUser, UserProfile


class CustomUserAdmin(UserAdmin):
    add_form = CustomUserCreationForm

    model = NewUser

    list_display = ('email', 'username', 'date_joined', 'last_login', 'is_admin', 'is_staff')
    search_fields = ('email', 'username',)
    readonly_fields = ('date_joined', 'last_login',)

    filter_horizontal = ()
    list_filter = ()
    fieldsets = ()


admin.site.register(custom_user_model, CustomUserAdmin)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add this code to CustomeUserAdmin:

```
class CustomUserAdmin(UserAdmin):
    .
    .
    .
    add_fieldsets = UserAdmin.add_fieldsets + (
        (None, {'fields': ('custom_field',)}),
    )
```

It looks like that form on django admin page is created base on add_fieldsets. I also don't know what add_form does actually.

For more information read django docs:
[django docs about admin](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/auth/customizing/#custom-users-and-django-contrib-admin), [A full example for Custome users in django admin](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/auth/customizing/#custom-users-admin-full-example)

> If you are using a custom ModelAdmin which is a subclass of django.contrib.auth.admin.UserAdmin, then you need to add your custom fields to fieldsets (for fields to be used in editing users) and to add_fieldsets (for fields to be used when creating a user).

Comment: Thank you for the hint @MatiYo.. This resolved my problem.. To get the result, which I expected, I added following line:

add_fieldsets = (
        (None, {'fields': ('custom_field',)}),
    )

the code example from the Django docs made username & password field appear first and the other fields below them.